# windows7 can't install NET-SNMP perl module

Tags: perl-module, net-snmp

I download net-snmp package from official website, and the version is 5.7.3 .

However, everytime I tried execute build.bat file it just show up :

[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL6yA.png)

Installed :

1. ActiveState Perl 5.20.1.2000
2. Microsoft Visual Studio professional 2012
3. Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.1L

What I have done :

1. set INCLUDE=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include

set LIB=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib\VC\static

execute vcvarsall.bat in VS2012 directory

execute build.bat in net-snmp directory

option set like this :

> 1. OpenSSL support:                enabled
> 2. Platform SDK support:           enabled
> 3. Install path:                   c:/usr
> 4. Install after build:            enabled
> 5. Perl modules:                   enabled
> 6. Install perl modules:           enabled
> 7. Quiet build (logged):           enabled
> 8. Debug mode:                     disabled
> 9. IPv6 transports (requires SDK): disabled
> 10. winExtDLL agent (requires SDK): enabled
> 11. Link type:                      static
> 12. Install development files       disabled
>
> F.  Finished - start build
>   Q.  Quit - abort build
>   
>   Then, it show like my picture.

Also, I uploaded the log output to my Dropbox

[output log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jv8bldie4rqdzhn/perlmake.out.txt?dl=0)

Comment: This doesn't look like programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `Net::SNMP` module directly from CPAN

```
cpan install Net::SNMP
```

Comment: thanks,but i need only SNMP not Net::SNMP
so i choose Linux this time and work fine